# java function to determine height of an image with the given width?

Tags: java, image, methods, dimensions, pixel

i'm having an image(some dimensions) i set the width of some pixel position. i need a java method to calculate the height of the image to display properly.

Comment: Your question is unclear - I've answered it as best I can understand what you're asking, but please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean you want to maintain the original aspect ratio, you're changing the width and you want to know the height? If so, it should be something like:

```
int newHeight = (oldHeight * newWidth) / oldWidth;
```

Performing multiplication then division will avoid some rounding errors, but may fail if the image is *huge* (i.e. if it overflows). An alternative is to use floating point:

```
int newHeight = (int) (oldHeight * ((double) newWidth / oldWidth));
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing it in BLackberry appln,if so use Display.getWidth() to calculate